# Регулярное выражение просмотр вперёд

Tags: php, регулярные-выражения

Можно ли одним регулярным выражением выделить валидную строку в группу, в которых одновременно `true` оба выражения:

- чтобы такие подстроки были `(!=арбуз|дыня)`
- а таких чтобы не было `(?!краснодарский|астраханский)`.

Пытался сконструировать кучу различных вариантов, но никак не выходило сделать чтобы оба выражения были в одном, работало только по отдельности.

Или это не возможно ?

Вдруг важно, данные в `Regex` будут попадать по строчке

Например:

```
арбуз сладкий // выделить
арбуз краснодарский
арбуз астраханский
дыня сладкая // выделить
дыня краснодарский
дыня астраханский
```

**UPD:** Ответ уже дали как достать верхнее - но могут быть данные и слитными

```
дынясладкая // выделить
арбузсладкий // выделить
```

Comment: пример текста приведите вдобавок, что из него вытаскивать надо

Comment: @teran добавил как пример. А так чтобы абсолютно универсально было в плане замены подстрок в выражении.

Comment: Вам захват валидной строки нужен, или просто проверить валидная она или нет?

Comment: @Theartofbeingalive захват валидной в группу

Comment: @Vipz, в строке еще слова встречаются, или только по два?

Comment: @Theartofbeingalive Да там вообще что угодно и сколько угодно может быть, как раз и пытаюсь найти универсальный вариант чтобы просто менять подстроки в выражении и всё.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> *Или это не возможно ?*

Если я правильно понял суть - вполне возможно

[~(?:арбуз|дыня)\h(?:(?!краснодарский|астраханский)\S+)~](https://regex101.com/r/0FxR5e/1)

---

Но справедливости ради должен заметить, что универсальных шаблонов не бывает. В контексте PHP *(метка php не указана в вопросе, поэтому язык для реализации выберите согласно ваших предпочтений)* можно конечно написать нечто подобное:

```
$str = 'арбуз сладкий // выделить
арбуз краснодарский
арбуз астраханский
дыня сладкая // выделить
дыня краснодарский
дыня астраханский';

$need = ['арбуз', 'дыня'];
$bad = ['краснодарский', 'астраханский'];

$need = join('|', $need);
$bad = join('|', $bad);
$arr = [];

! preg_match_all("~(?:$need)\h?(?:(?!$bad)\S+)~", $str, $arr) ?: $arr = $arr[0];

var_dump($arr);
```

---

Результатом будет массив:

```
array(2) {
  [0]=> "арбуз сладкий"
  [1]=> "дыня сладкая"
}
```

Comment: Спасибо!
Но видимо невозможно( там любые данные могут быть, в том числе и слитные. Можете разъяснить что такое `~` ?

Comment: Для PHP я написал пример для _почти_ любых данных, а символ "~" - это ограничитель шаблона. Посмотрите на пример в песочнице, я подкорректировал с учётом слитных слов: [см. демо](https://ideone.com/rBz7Cm)

Comment: Блин, вроде всё работает о_О

Comment: @Vipz и ещё [вариант](https://ideone.com/tQ5pgz). Если работает, ткните на галку возле ответа :)

Comment: А как всё строку в которой эти подстроки есть, запихнуть в группу ? что то только кусок попадает https://regex101.com/r/fEUfIo/3

Comment: Вы об [этом](https://regex101.com/r/fEUfIo/4) ?

Comment: Да) что то сам не стал трогать, боялся сломать xD Спасибо вам!